# What tools are built using themselves?

Tags: bootstrapping

I am curious about what tools are used to build the next version of themselves.

For example, Delphi has long claimed that "[Delphi is written in Delphi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Delphi#Products_developed_with_Delphi)".

I assume Visual Studio is written using Visual Studio.

What are some other examples of tools that written in themselves?

Comment: This brings up the age old question: "What came first, C or the C Compiler?"

Comment: Aside: Does anyone have any reference to the assertion that Delphi is written in Delphi?

Comment: Programmers build the next version of themselves!

Comment: @Conrad: I once attended a demo of Delphi 2010, and Nick Hodges opened Delphi on his laptop, inside Delphi.  Then the room exploded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bjarne Stroustrup mentioned in [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/dne.html) that the first C++ compiler was written in C++.

I've just noticed this is also a question in his [FAQ](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#bootstrapping):

> The first C++ compiler (Cfront) was
>   written in C++. To build that, I first
>   used C to write a "C with
>   Classes"-to-C preprocessor. "C with
>   Classes" was a C dialect that became
>   the immediate ancestor to C++. That
>   preprocessor translated "C with
>   Classes" constructs (such as classes
>   and constructors) into C. It was a
>   traditional preprocessor that didn't
>   understand all of the language, left
>   most of the type checking for the C
>   compiler to do, and translated
>   individual constructs without complete
>   knowledge. I then wrote the first
>   version of Cfront in "C with Classes".

Answer (score 11):

Interestingly, the VB.NET & C# compilers themselves are written in unmanaged C++ (leading to the C++ team's T-Shirt: "My compiler compiled yours").  The C# team hopes to have a fully managed-C# hosted C# compiler for VS2010.

Comment: So C# is not written in C#, and yet this answer gets 6 up votes... This would be a counter-example or possibly an answer to a different question.  How cool is that?

Comment: I don't think it's even correct that the C#-written C# compiler is going to be in VS2010 - I think it's for after that.

Comment: @S.Lott: This answer is upvoted because it contains useful or interesting information. Though don't know why it's marked as accepted. :)

Comment: they could just take mono's compiler (it's X11/MIT licensed) but NIH! NIH! NIH! ;)

Comment: @S.Lott and @Alexander Prokofyev - You guys are probably right- it does not make sense for this to be the accepted answer.  I've moved it to a different answer, although this was still quite interesting.

Comment: Don't leave us in suspense!  It's 2010 ... did VS ship with a C# compiler written in C#?  :-)

Comment: C# is written in C#...

Comment: @Rainb Well, now it is.  I wrote that comment 15 years ago...

Comment: did ms happen to open source the last c++ code that compiled the c# compiler?

Answer (score 8):

This is off-topic, but strictly speaking, it is an example of a tool which builds itself.

The [reprap](http://www.reprap.org/bin/view/Main/WebHome) - an open-source 3d prototyping machine, which recently gave 'birth' to "its first complete working replicated copy".

I love this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Generically speaking, C compilers are usually written in C...  *nix kernels are compiled on *nix, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Also, there's the [pypy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/home.html) project which provides a Python interpreter written in Python.

Comment: No, that's cheating. PyPy isn't just a call to eval :-)

Answer (score 4):

When gcc (the Gnu C compiler http://gcc.gnu.org/) was not available widely, you had to compile it from source, compiling stage1 compiler, then compile stage2 with stage1, till you have your final compiler. I assume it must be the same today.

Comment: The other normal way was to use a gcc cross compiler to compile it for the new platform.

Comment: gcc usually only compiles with a very restricted range of gcc versions.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another example: Mono's C# compiler is [self hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hosting) - i.e. it's written in C# and used to compile itself.

*Dog fooding* refers to the more general practice of a company using its own product internally, especially during its development.

Comment: I wish I knew how the C# compiler is bootstrapped when you download full source and compile.

Comment: Me too :) [ten characters...]

Answer (score 3):

Lots of folks like to look at how [Lisp can be implemented in Lisp](http://www.cs.aau.dk/~normark/prog3-03/html/notes/languages_themes-list-in-lisp.html).

Answer (score 3):

[Squeak](http://www.squeak.org) is a Smalltalk-80 implementation written in itself.

> even its virtual machine is written entirely in Smalltalk making it easy to debug, analyze, and change.

Answer (score 3):

Sun's Java compiler has long been written in Java. However, [recent work](https://maxine.dev.java.net/) is writing a JIT compiler in Java as well. This is the JVM component that converts Java byte code to native processor instructions.

Answer (score 2):

We use to develop using RealBasic.  The IDE is written in itself, or so I've been lead to believe.

Comment: Yes, starting with REALbasic 2005 the IDE has been written in REALbasic.  The compiler, however, is not.

Answer (score 2):

ghc, the Haskell compiler, is *mostly* written in Haskell.

Comment: Part of the runtime system is written in C and C-- (the latter being an intermediate language developed for use in GHC).

Answer (score 2):

[tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc) is another self-hosting C compiler for x86 and ARM. Its claim to fame is being, well, tiny (100k or so for preprocessor, compiler, assembler, and linker).

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that pretty much any tool that's part of the typical development process would be involved in its own development, to whatever extent possible. This includes:

- certain programming languages, especially compiled ones
- IDEs
- text editors
- version control systems
- bug trackers
- build systems

If you're on a team building one of these tools, and you're not developing it for a specific niche that doesn't apply to your team, I don't know why you wouldn't use it to build itself. Having developers be users of the product is one of the best ways to find possible improvements.

Answer (score 2):

For the AmigaOS there was a third party Basic interpreter (don't remember the name) for which you could later buy a compiler. The compiler was delivered as source, so you had to use the interpreter to run the compiler to compile itself...

To cite Kent Beck:

> ...it may seem a bit like performing brain surgery on yourself.

Comment: Stuff like this is so cool! And think about it: we all work this way internally. DNA, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server build themselves.   It's called [dogfooding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogfooding), a term which if not originating in Microsoft, it certainly [likes](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2003/02/21/2743.aspx)

Comment: Um. No, they weren't. They did USE Team Foundation server when developing it; but TFS is not a development language as Delphi, C++, C#, etc are

Comment: you're right, i wasn't reading build as just compiled but as in that they used it, which could be construed as an answer to this.   it''s a rather fluffy question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle Application Express](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/application_express/index.html) is a web application development tool that is built in itself.

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) is generally built and developed using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly typical to have a languages compiler written in its own language.  This is called [self-hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hosting) or [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)).

Answer (score 0):

[Maven2](http://maven.apache.org/) is built using Maven2.
Ok, it's not built (i.e. *written*) using itself, as it is a tool to build (i.e. *compile*) project, but it is using its own code to compile...

Answer (score 0):

I was amazed with [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

In short it has been described as Javascript "compiler" using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am building an IDE-based code generator, and I am using it to build itself. If fact, as Stroustrup did, I am first building a valid generator model and using a pre-processor to build the final C++ code to compile. Once I have a good working version of the IDE, I'll start using it to build further versions of itself.

It's like giving a new dimension to the meaning of "recursive programming"!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK does the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) build itself first with the installed java and afterwards with itself.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally the Jetbrains team uses its own IDE [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) to develop this IDE.

I assume this is true for most IDE vendors.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when building EMACS from source, all of the ELISP code is bootstrapped. I found that quite noteworthy.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're asking for, but the entire development environment for Revolution http://www.runrev.com is built using Revolution itself, and the source (except for small parts that enforce the license) is completely exposed in source form. So if you don't like the way the dev environment is implemented, you can change it. Find a bug, fix it. You can also easily build additional development tools and integrate them.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the Smalltalk-80 answer an uptick. Best, most elegant example I can think of. The question also reminds me of a slightly related problem that used to be popular: write a program that outputs itself. Not the same level of bootstrapping, but a fun little programming puzzle for your amusement. Maybe not possible in all languages?

Answer (score 0):

Ada and Forth

Answer (score 0):

The old Watcom C/C++ compiler was built using itself.

Answer (score 0):

Kragen Sitaker's [Ur-Scheme](http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/sw/urscheme/) is a fine example of a *small* nontrivial compiler written in itself. That page links to several more good sources in that vein.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin called [nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/) which assists and accelerates code exploration. I've been using it as part of my development since the moment it was stable enough and I just can't live without it now (well, it has the tendency of becoming a habit very quickly :-).

For me it's "eat your own dog food", but it really helps. This also raises my confidence in the product.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way most compilers work. Yes, I know, there are exceptions, but it might actually be shorter to list those exceptions.

In the meantime, I know that [gnat](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnat/) requires an Ada compiler (gnat will do) to compile from sources. GCC requires some kind of C compiler, and has a bootstrap phase to build itself using itself (or at least it did 15 years ago when last I went through that pain). The creator of Draco I belive told me that it was written in Draco.